# Testing with Golang, redis and time

Tags: go, redigo

I was trying to test a bit with Redis for the first time and I bumped into some confusion with `HGET`/`HSET`/`HGETALL`. My main problem was that I needed to store time, and I wanted to use a hash as I'll continuously update the time.

At first I read about how a `MarshalBinary` function such as this would save me:

```golang
func (f Foo) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(f)
}
```

What that did was that it saved the struct as a json string, but only as a string and not as an actual Redis hash. What I ended up doing in the end was a fairly large boilerplate code that makes my struct I want to save into a map, and that one is properly stored as a hash in Redis.

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Number int       `json:"number"`
    ATime  time.Time `json:"atime"`
    String string    `json:"astring"`
}

func (f Foo) toRedis() map[string]interface{} {
    res := make(map[string]interface{})
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(f)
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    if rt.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        rt = rt.Elem()
        rv = rv.Elem()
    }
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        f := rt.Field(i)
        v := rv.Field(i)
        switch t := v.Interface().(type) {
        case time.Time:
            res[f.Tag.Get("json")] = t.Format(time.RFC3339)
        default:
            res[f.Tag.Get("json")] = t
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Then to parse back into my Foo struct when calling `HGetAll(..).Result()`, I'm getting the result as a `map[string]string` and create a new Foo with these functions:

```golang
func setRequestParam(arg *Foo, i int, value interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(arg).Elem()
    f := v.Field(i)
    if f.IsValid() {
        if f.CanSet() {
            if f.Kind() == reflect.String {
                f.SetString(value.(string))
                return
            } else if f.Kind() == reflect.Int {
                f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
                return
            } else if f.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
            }
        }
    }
}

func fromRedis(data map[string]string) (f Foo) {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(f)
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(f)

    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        field := rt.Field(i)
        v := rv.Field(i)
        switch v.Interface().(type) {
        case time.Time:
            if val, ok := data[field.Tag.Get("json")]; ok {
                if ti, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, val); err == nil {
                    setRequestParam(&f, i, ti)
                }
            }
        case int:
            if val, ok := data[field.Tag.Get("json")]; ok {
                in, _ := strconv.ParseInt(val, 10, 32)
                setRequestParam(&f, i, int(in))

            }
        default:
            if val, ok := data[field.Tag.Get("json")]; ok {
                setRequestParam(&f, i, val)
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

The whole code in its ungloryness is [here](https://go.dev/play/p/H72dKF7Axok)

I'm thinking that there must be a saner way to solve this problem? Or am I forced to do something like this? The struct I need to store only contains ints, strings and time.Times.

*edit
The comment field is a bit short so doing an edit instead:

I did originally solve it like 'The Fool' suggested in comments and as an answer. The reason I changed to the above part, while more complex a solution, I think it's more robust for changes. If I go with a hard coded map solution, I'd "have to" have:

- Constants with hash keys for the fields, since they'll be used at least in two places (from and to Redis), it'll be a place for silly mistakes not picked up by the compiler. Can of course skip that but knowing my own spelling it's likely to happen
- If someone just wants to add a new field and doesn't know the code well, it will compile just fine but the new field won't be added in Redis. An easy mistake to do, especially for junior developers being a bit naive, or seniors with too much confidence.
- I can put these helper functions in a library, and things will just magically work for all our code when a time or complex type is needed.

My intended question/hope though was: Do I really have to jump through hoops like this to store time in Redis hashes with go? Fair, time.Time isn't a primitive and Redis isn't a (no)sql database, but I would consider timestamps in cache a very common use case (in my case a heartbeat to keep track of timed out sessions together with metadata enough to permanently store it, thus the need to update them). But maybe I'm misusing Redis, and I should rather have two entries, one for the data and one for the timestamp, which would then leave me with two simple get/set functions taking in time.Time and returning time.Time.

Comment: It's too generic and doesn't look idiomatic. Usually you know better how you data looks like. It's better to work with structs in go. You can at least scan into a struct, https://redis.uptrace.dev/guide/scanning-hash-fields.html, time.Time is not supported, though, so you may want to save the timestamps as a string on the struct.

Comment: I think you can look for a lib called mapstructure - it main objective is to convert `map[string]interface{}` to structure but it can do the opposite.

Comment: @TheFool: The problem is the exactly that redis doesn't handle time and that's what I'm trying to get around here. I have to insert the time as Unix (bad idea since a zero Time doesn't work with that) or string, and HSet doesn't accept structs as input so I have to insert it as a map[string]interface{}. When scanning into a struct, I would then have to have an intermediate struct with the time fields as strings, and then create the target struct converting the strings to time.Time. That's the reason for the code block. And trying to do it so I don't have to change in 3 places if struct changes

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj, yes that would solve the storing and fetching of structs. But redis doesn't support storing time.Time, so I'd still have to have a step in between making it a string? From what I could see you can only get back map[string]string, map[string]interface{} or scan into a struct. And since time will be serialized as a string when stored in Redis, it'll be a string also in a map[string]interface{} and that will fail when straight converting back map => struct?

Comment: You know your struct, why do you need reflection?

Comment: @Jon please check answer and let me know if need more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`redigo/redis#Args.AddFlat`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Args.AddFlat) to convert struct to redis hash we can map the value using `redis` tag.

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"

  "time"
  "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

type Foo struct {
    Number  int64     `json:"number"  redis:"number"`
    ATime   time.Time `json:"atime"   redis:"atime"`
    AString string    `json:"astring" redis:"astring"`
}

func main() {
  c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  defer c.Close()

  t1 := time.Now().UTC()
  var foo Foo
  foo.Number = 10000000000
  foo.ATime = t1
  foo.AString = "Hello"

  tmp := redis.Args{}.Add("id1").AddFlat(&foo)
  if _, err := c.Do("HMSET", tmp...); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  v, err := redis.StringMap(c.Do("HGETALL", "id1"))
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", v)
}
```

Then to update `ATime` you can use redis `HSET`

```golang
if _, err := c.Do("HMSET", "id1", "atime", t1.Add(-time.Hour * (60 * 60 * 24))); err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
}
```

And to retrieve it back to struct we have to do some [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) magic

```golang
func structFromMap(src map[string]string, dst interface{}) error {
  dt := reflect.TypeOf(dst).Elem()
  dv := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem()

  for i := 0; i < dt.NumField(); i++ {
    sf := dt.Field(i)
    sv := dv.Field(i)
    if v, ok := src[strings.ToLower(sf.Name)]; ok {
      switch sv.Interface().(type) {
        case time.Time:
          format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
          ti, err := time.Parse(format, v)
          if err != nil {
            return err
          }
          sv.Set(reflect.ValueOf(ti))
        case int, int64:
          x, err := strconv.ParseInt(v, 10, sv.Type().Bits())
          if err != nil {
            return err
          }
          sv.SetInt(x)
        default:
          sv.SetString(v)
      }
    }
  }

  return nil
}
```

#### Final Code

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"

  "time"
  "reflect"
  "strings"
  "strconv"

  "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

type Foo struct {
    Number  int64     `json:"number"  redis:"number"`
    ATime   time.Time `json:"atime"   redis:"atime"`
    AString string    `json:"astring" redis:"astring"`
}

func main() {
  c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  defer c.Close()

  t1 := time.Now().UTC()
  var foo Foo
  foo.Number = 10000000000
  foo.ATime = t1
  foo.AString = "Hello"

  tmp := redis.Args{}.Add("id1").AddFlat(&foo)
  if _, err := c.Do("HMSET", tmp...); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  v, err := redis.StringMap(c.Do("HGETALL", "id1"))
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", v)

  if _, err := c.Do("HMSET", "id1", "atime", t1.Add(-time.Hour * (60 * 60 * 24))); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  var foo2 Foo
  structFromMap(v, &foo2)
  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", foo2)
}

func structFromMap(src map[string]string, dst interface{}) error {
  dt := reflect.TypeOf(dst).Elem()
  dv := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem()

  for i := 0; i < dt.NumField(); i++ {
    sf := dt.Field(i)
    sv := dv.Field(i)
    if v, ok := src[strings.ToLower(sf.Name)]; ok {
      switch sv.Interface().(type) {
        case time.Time:
          format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
          ti, err := time.Parse(format, v)
          if err != nil {
            return err
          }
          sv.Set(reflect.ValueOf(ti))
        case int, int64:
          x, err := strconv.ParseInt(v, 10, sv.Type().Bits())
          if err != nil {
            return err
          }
          sv.SetInt(x)
        default:
          sv.SetString(v)
      }
    }
  }

  return nil
}
```

**Note:** The struct field name is matched with the `redis` tag